# What is the implementation for dilation method for gray scale images?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, image-morphology

I made a program to implement dilation method for gray scale images without using any predefined function. Here is the code I wrote in python:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('dil.png', 0)
cv.imshow('Original', img)

def find_max(k):
        mx = k[0]
        for i in range(1, len(k)):
            if k[i] > mx:
            mx = k[i]
        return mx


mask=[0]*9
mask[0] = 0
mask[1] = 1
mask[2] = 0
mask[3] = 1
mask[4] = 1
mask[5] = 1
mask[6] = 0
mask[7] = 1
mask[8] = 0

for m in range(1, img.shape[0]-1):
    for n in range(1, img.shape[1]-1):
        mask[6] += img[m-1,n-1] 
        mask[7] += img[m,n-1]
        mask[8] += img[m+1,n-1] 
        mask[3] += img[m-1,n]
        mask[4] += img[m,n]
        mask[5] += img[m+1,n]
        mask[0] += img[m-1,n+1]
        mask[1] += img[m,n+1]
        mask[2] += img[m+1,n+1]

        u = find_max(mask)
        img[m,n]= u
cv.imshow('Dilated', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used here 3X3 kernel. Please do correct if anything else is also wrong. I am a beginner and just curious to done this without using direct functions.

Comment: Two things... 1) you don't seem to clear `mask[]` as you come to each new pixel, so you'll be adding to whatever you had for the previous pixel, and 2) you should not try to do it *"in-place"* - make a new, separate output image and build your results there and not overwriting your input image else you will mix the two up.